# Переназначение кнопок на mac

Tags: macos

Занялся разработкой в xcode. Так как до настоящего мака неделю-другую необходимо подождать, вышел из положения эмулятором на win7 (vmware + macos). Сразу же столкнулся с тем, что для очень многих действий необходима кнопка command, ну и само собой разумеется, что на стандартной клавиатуре её нет. Возник вопрос - а есть ли способ переназначить клавиши на произвольные в mac. Пробовал через настройки, там есть 4 свободные клавиши для переназначения - ctrl, alt, capslock, command. По какой то причине результата переназначения не вижу, сейчас попробую перезагрузить виртуальную машину, но даже если и получится - лишаться однай из этих клавиш затратно - хотелось бы задействовать ненужную в мэке кнопку win например. Есть ли какой то способ это сделать?

Comment: вопрос-то решили?? или мак приехал раньше??

Comment: @Akuma925, столкнулись с такой же проблемой? На виртуальной машине cmd завязана на Win Key

Comment: нет, просто вопрос увидел, поздно , да и решение один в один.